# Can't connect to vsftpd on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ftp

I started the vsftpd on Ubuntu 10.04, but can't connect to it.

The error says(FTP Client):

```
Status: Connecting to 124.205.xx.xx:21...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I've checked the server status, and vsftpd is running:

```
$ ps ax | grep vsftpd
23646 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/vsftpd
23650 pts/1    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto vsftpd
```

port 21 is under listening as well:

```
$ netstat -tlnp | grep 21
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I can connect to localhost:

```
$ ftp localhost
Connected to localhost.
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (localhost:jlee): 
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

Here is iptables output

```
$ sudo iptables -vL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 191 packets, 144K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 124 packets, 28502 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: What does netstat -tlnp report? You just tried to list all the open udp ports with your netstat command, that can't be right... :-)

Comment: Is 124.205.xx.xx a static or dynamic IP?

Comment: Can you post tcpdump outputs from both client and server side?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your ftp client is on activ or passiv mode.
If it's on passiv mode, you have to add some parameters. Something like this :

pasv_enable=YES
pasv_promiscuous=NO
pasv_min_port=40000 as you want
pasv_max_port=41000
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (your ip)
port_promiscuous=NO

Answer (score 0):

I just installed vsftpd with `apt-get install vsftpd` on my Ubuntu 10.04 laptop, and the daemon worked out of the box.

Have you modified the vsftpd configuration files?

Does `ftp localhost` work for you if you try to do that on your server?

Do you have iptables enabled? Does `iptables -vL` list some rules?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the output of `ftp localhost` and `iptables -vL`, please take a look at it. I used apt-get install vsftpd too, and it worked. But after a server sudden down, it doesn't work now

Answer (score 0):

It's not your server firewall, it's not your vsftp configuration, it's something between you and your server =P

Can you connect from your pc to any other ftp server? Can you connect to your ftp from another host?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it might be apparmor daemon which might be denying you to connect it to your 
FTP server , disable apparmor and see if it helps

```
 service apparmor stop
```